# AND OR causing more results to appear than should

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display results for that match a specific timeframe - which works fine. However, I wanted to add a clause that would say that the results shown must be either party_type `1` or `2`.

So I did this

```
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
AND PARTY_TYPE='1'
OR PARTY_TYPE='2'
GROUP BY events.ENTRANCE_PRICE
```

But now it's showing some additional events from yesterday... What's interesting though, is that it's not showing any events that are further back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
AND (PARTY_TYPE='1'
OR PARTY_TYPE='2')
GROUP BY events.ENTRANCE_PRICE
```

Slightly cleaner version of whole thing would be

```
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
AND (PARTY_TYPE IN (1,2))
GROUP BY events.ENTRANCE_PRICE
```

You might also want to check out [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/13) to learn more about using Multiple WHERE conditions.

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/operator-precedence.html), `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.  Therefore your current filter is evaluated as:

```
WHERE (      start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
         AND   end_datetime <  '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
         AND PARTY_TYPE='1'
      )   OR PARTY_TYPE='2'
```

You should add parentheses to force the precedence that suits your requirements:

```
WHERE       start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
        AND   end_datetime <  '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
        AND  (PARTY_TYPE='1' OR PARTY_TYPE='2')
```

Or, alternatively, use MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator:

```
WHERE       start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
        AND   end_datetime <  '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
        AND  PARTY_TYPE IN ('1','2')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use brackets to make sure the boolean is evaluated as you require it.  In particular, group together

```
(PARTY_TYPE='1' OR PARTY_TYPE='2')
```

to give you

```
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
AND (PARTY_TYPE='1' OR PARTY_TYPE='2')
GROUP BY events.ENTRANCE_PRICE
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query there is ambiguity in level of which AND and OR act. You want to put on the same level two conditions: about the date start, date end(and these are ok)and the party_type (either 1 or 0). Instead in your query you treat them as four independent ones.Set it like this:

```
    start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
    end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
    AND (PARTY_TYPE='1' OR PARTY_TYPE='2')
```

I hope it helps.